# Сохранение конечного этапа анимации изображения

Tags: java, android, анимация

Есть обычная анимация масштабирования

```
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.3"
    android:toYScale="1.3"
    android:duration="1000"
    />
```

Мне нужно, чтобы, по окончании анимации, изображение оставалось в состоянии Scale=1.3, а не переходило в начальную фазу Scale=1.0.

Пытался программно установить, чтобы по окончании анимации нужное изображение становилось Scale=1.3, но работает некорректно, картинка дергается.

```
scale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            start1_value=1;
            Start1.setScaleX((float) 1.3);
            Start1.setScaleY((float) 1.3);

        }

    });
```

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ObjectAnimator:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1.3f);
ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.3f);
AnimatorSet scale = new AnimatorSet();

scaleX.setDuration(1000);
scaleY.setDuration(1000);    
scale.play(scaleX).with(scaleY);

scale.start();
```

Или для ImageView:

```
imageView.animate().scaleX(toX).scaleY(toY).setDuration(1000);
```